# pyCurl - delete all files in WebDAV directory

Tags: pycurl

I want to delete all files in a WebDav directory with pyCurl. I was able to delete one specific file with the following code:

```
def filedelete(url, filename, upload_user, upload_pw):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    url = url + filename
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE")
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, upload_user + ":" + upload_pw)

    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

For my understanding it is not possible to use wildcards in curl. So the only solution for this task is to read a list of all files in this directory and delete every file. How can I read the list of files and is it possible to send a list of filenames/urls with one command to reduce the load on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution by myself with the following functions. Perhaps it is not the most elegant solution but it is working for me.

The function `filedelete` deletes all files on the WebDav Url `url`. For this the function calls first the function `listfiles`. This function creates an array of all files and folders on the `url`. After that each file is deleted individually in the function `filedelete`.

```
def filedelete(url, upload_user, upload_pw):
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    host = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    print(host)

    c = pycurl.Curl()

    # Get all files in directory
    files = listfiles(url, upload_user, upload_pw)

    print(files)

    # Delete all files in directory
    for url in files:
        url = host + url
        c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
        c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE")
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
        c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, upload_user + ":" + upload_pw)
        c.perform()
    
    c.close()
    
    return True

def listfiles(url, upload_user, upload_pw):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PROPFIND")
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, upload_user + ":" + upload_pw)
    c.perform()
    c.close()

    body = buffer.getvalue().decode('iso-8859-1')
    
    # create element tree object
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(body))
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    files = []
    for items in root.findall('./{DAV:}response/{DAV:}href'):
        files.append(items.text)

    files.pop(0)
    files.reverse()

    return files
```